# How to reset docker-for-mac v2.1.0.0 kubernetes from the command line?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am constantly creating new clusters for development and I dislike going into "Troubleshooting" every time to reset the cluster.

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickest way I can think of is to blat the kubernetes etcd data.

You will need to have "Show system containers" turned on in Docker.

Please note, this is **super destructive** and not thoroughly tested (other than to see if it runs). There's probably **horrible side effects** from using it. Docker for Desktop maintains a lot more state on disk than just etcd. There's also an **`rm -rf`** in there which you should never trust someone on the internet telling you to run! But here we go...

This will:

- Find the `k8s_etcd_etcd-*` container and remove all etcd data from it.
- Force delete all containers with a name of `k8s_*`.
- Docker for Desktop will reinitialise the containers.
- Kubernetes will reinitialise the etcd database (hopefully)

One liner:

```
docker exec $(docker ps -q --filter 'name=k8s_etcd_etcd-*' -l) rm -rf /var/lib/etcd/member \
  && docker rm -f $(docker ps -q --filter 'name=k8s_*')
```

or as a script with a bit more output:

```
#!/bin/bash -uex

etcd_container=$(docker ps -q --filter 'name=k8s_etcd_etcd-*' -l)
docker exec "$etcd_container" rm -rf /var/lib/etcd/member;
all_k8s_containers=$(docker ps -q --filter 'name=k8s_*')
docker rm -f $all_k8s_containers
```